# こうして使い物になるのは俺がいるからじゃないか？ meaning

Tags: translation

From what I know, Koshite is "this is why", tsukiamono is "useless", ni naru no wa is "become" and orega iru kara is "because I'm here". So is it right to read it as "this is why it became useless, because I'm here, isn't it right?"

They talk about a house that had been neglected. Full sentence:

> 荒れ放題だった家がこうして使い物になるのは、俺がいるからじゃないか？

Comment: 使い物にならない could means "useless". You don't have the negative here...

Answer (score 3):

> 「荒{あ}れ放題{ほうだい}だった家{いえ}がこうして使{つか}い物{もの}になるのは、俺{おれ}がいるからじゃないか？ 」

Not sure how you wound up thinking that 「使い物になる」 would mean "***useless***".  It actually means the opposite of that; It means "***to be fit for use***".

> "The reason that the house that had been left to dilapidation is now fit to use like this is because I am here, isn't it?"